# Serious bug with Symfony security component when using parameters in firewall map?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I think I may found a serious issue with the firewall component in Symfony **using long parameter names**. I'l posting it as a question for getting some confirmation.

Take this `parameters.yml`:

```
router.request_context.host: my.domain.com
domain: my.domain.com
```

When use the short one (`%domain%`) it in `security.yml`:

```
access_control:
  - { host: admin.%domain%, path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
  - { host: admin.%domain%, path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
```

All works as expected. Relevant section in generated `appProdProjectContainer.php` (returns added for redability):

```
protected function getSecurity_Firewall_Map_Context_AdminService()
{
    // ...
    $h = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestMatcher(
        '^/login$', 'admin.my.domain.com'
    );
    $i = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestMatcher(
        '^/', 'admin.my.domain.com'
    );
    $j = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessMap();
   // ...
}
```

**The problem is when you use `%router.request_context.host%` it get's translated into localhost, that is your firewall will not apply to production sites.**

Note that `%router.request_context.host%` is used for sending mails using console commands:  using it in `security.yml` can lead to a huge security hole in your application.

Comment: If you think you found a security issue, you shouldn't announce it publicly, but follow the reporting procedure: http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/security.html

Having said that, I fail to see how the problem described is a security issue. It looks like misconfiguration/misuse. I will quickly verify in a fresh environment.

Comment: It seems to be indeed a bug. Please report it to https://github.com/symfony/symfony

Comment: @JakubZalas thank you for your feedback. It's not a security bug because it depends on the configuration. But it's not a misuse because parameters are allowed in `security.yml`. Anywasy I opened this issue, hoping it gets resolved: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11440